# Callback when logged on via PAM 2F authentication

Tags: pam

Whenever authentication is done via PAM, and the module that successfully completes the login is pam_yubico.so then I want a script to be invoked.

```
 e.g: user does sudo:
 -> user is not configured for 2FA on sudo
 -> user logs in with password
 -> callback is not invoked

e.g.2: same user does ssh login:
-> ssh requires 2FA for this user
-> user logs in with password & yubikey
-> user login accepted
-> invoke callback

e.g.3: another user does sudo:
 -> user configuration has 2FA required for sudo
 -> user types pass and presses yubikey
 -> user login accepted
 -> invoke callbak
```

So specifically I need the callback to trigger whenever a user successfully authenticates with 2 factor.

Just running a script from bash_profile or rc is not what I want. The callback needs to be invoked regardless of where the 2F was used (kde, sudo, ssh su ...)

Answer (score 0):

Executing a command after a successful module should be doable, skip to pam_exec.so with `success=${num lines to skip}`

man 8 pam_exec

```
    auth sufficient                  pam_unix.so
    auth [success=1 default=ignore]  foo_2fa.so some_other=options
    auth requisite                   pam_deny.so
    auth optional                    pam_exec.so debug /path/to/my/script.sh
```

I didn't test the above so you'll probably have to tweak it as well as make sure its secure.

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with that. As soon as I add `[success=n] ` logins start failing with `PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib/security/required): /usr/lib/security/required: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and `PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib/security/required`. Looking through the man pages of pam_yubico and comparing it with those of pam_deny and pam_succeed_if it seems that pam_yubico does not support the passing of [success=, default=] conditions...

Comment: `/usr/lib/security/required` doesn't look like a valid module.  I'd imagine that there is a typo in your config file.

Also, If reading `man pam.conf` is anything to go by, the success behavior handled by pam itself.  The module in question should have nothing to do with it.

As an aside, this works for me with pam_krb.so.